# problem with "pip install tsfresh[matrixprofile]" and "pip install matrixprofile"

Tags: python, pip, conda, tsfresh, matrix-profile

I am working with the library tsfresh in the latest version, but during the feature extraction a receive a warning (WARNING - Dependency not available for matrix_profile, this feature will be disabled!) and then an exception.

I try to make a new conda environment with python 3.8 and use pip install tsfresh[matrixprofile] but pip can't find the package.

So i try to make pip install matrixprofile but i receive the following error:

```
(tsfresh__py_3.8) alessio@Alessios-MBP Alessio % pip install matrixprofile

Collecting matrixprofile
  Using cached matrixprofile-1.1.10.tar.gz (331 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [47 lines of output]
      /private/var/folders/s_/wcbhtkn953d2yl21zd8frrsr0000gn/T/pip-install-t8b6g2j3/matrixprofile_a5506b66a087426399cf87c5232c0f73/setup.py:4: _DeprecatedInstaller: setuptools.installer and fetch_build_eggs are deprecated.
      !!
      
              ********************************************************************************
              Requirements should be satisfied by a PEP 517 installer.
              If you are using pip, you can try `pip install --use-pep517`.
              ********************************************************************************
      
      !!
        dist.Distribution().fetch_build_eggs(['cython>=0.x', 'numpy>=1.16.2', 'wheel'])
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/Users/alessio/miniforge3/envs/tsfresh__py_3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/packaging/requirements.py", line 35, in __init__
          parsed = _parse_requirement(requirement_string)
        File "/Users/alessio/miniforge3/envs/tsfresh__py_3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/packaging/_parser.py", line 64, in parse_requirement
          return _parse_requirement(Tokenizer(source, rules=DEFAULT_RULES))
        File "/Users/alessio/miniforge3/envs/tsfresh__py_3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/packaging/_parser.py", line 82, in _parse_requirement
          url, specifier, marker = _parse_requirement_details(tokenizer)
        File "/Users/alessio/miniforge3/envs/tsfresh__py_3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/packaging/_parser.py", line 126, in _parse_requirement_details
          marker = _parse_requirement_marker(
        File "/Users/alessio/miniforge3/envs/tsfresh__py_3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/packaging/_parser.py", line 147, in _parse_requirement_marker
          tokenizer.raise_syntax_error(
        File "/Users/alessio/miniforge3/envs/tsfresh__py_3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/packaging/_tokenizer.py", line 165, in raise_syntax_error
          raise ParserSyntaxError(
      pkg_resources.extern.packaging._tokenizer.ParserSyntaxError: Expected end or semicolon (after version specifier)
          cython>=0.x
                ~~~^
      
      The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
      
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/private/var/folders/s_/wcbhtkn953d2yl21zd8frrsr0000gn/T/pip-install-t8b6g2j3/matrixprofile_a5506b66a087426399cf87c5232c0f73/setup.py", line 4, in <module>
          dist.Distribution().fetch_build_eggs(['cython>=0.x', 'numpy>=1.16.2', 'wheel'])
        File "/Users/alessio/miniforge3/envs/tsfresh__py_3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 907, in fetch_build_eggs
          return _fetch_build_eggs(self, requires)
        File "/Users/alessio/miniforge3/envs/tsfresh__py_3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/installer.py", line 38, in _fetch_build_eggs
          resolved_dists = pkg_resources.working_set.resolve(
        File "/Users/alessio/miniforge3/envs/tsfresh__py_3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 806, in resolve
          requirements = list(requirements)[::-1]
        File "/Users/alessio/miniforge3/envs/tsfresh__py_3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3174, in __init__
          super(Requirement, self).__init__(requirement_string)
        File "/Users/alessio/miniforge3/envs/tsfresh__py_3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/packaging/requirements.py", line 37, in __init__
          raise InvalidRequirement(str(e)) from e
      pkg_resources.extern.packaging.requirements.InvalidRequirement: Expected end or semicolon (after version specifier)
          cython>=0.x
                ~~~^
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

i try to install different version of matrixprofile and same error occure, i try also to use different version of python.

Comment: This is a bug in the library. It should still be supported in older versions of pip though. Downgrade your pip and try again. Found [this PR](https://github.com/matrix-profile-foundation/matrixprofile/pull/110) that would fix the bug when it's merged.

Comment: According to the [source code](https://tsfresh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/tsfresh/feature_extraction/feature_calculators.html#matrix_profile), **"This feature is not supported anymore, since matrixprofile does not up to date with latest Python releases. To use it, you can install the extra with pip install tsfresh[matrixprofile].".**
I attempted "pip install tsfresh[matrixprofile]" on Python3.10, however, it failed during pip install. I recommend you to get the matrix profile value with stumpy. It is not difficult.